# WPF user control does not resize with main window

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls

I'm trying to make a WPF user control that includes two group boxes and two `ListView`s in each group box. Here is the XAML code for the user control:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="TestGroupControl.TestGroupControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="500" Width="700" MinWidth="300" MinHeight="200">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="225*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="225*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Test Data" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="testDataGroupBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ListView Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="testDataListView" ></ListView>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Test Parameters" Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="testParametersGroupBox">
                <Grid>
                    <ListView Margin="2,2,2,2" Name="testParametersListView" ></ListView>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

The problem I am facing is that when I try to resize the main window holding the user control, the user control won't follow the parent window and resize as well.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're specifying the `Height` and `Width` properties as fixed values in the UserControl.  Remove those properties, and set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties of the control instance in the main window to `Stretch`.  That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

İf You Use a ViewBox and a Canvas on your user control will fix all the mainwindow sizes

```
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Stretch="Uniform">

  <canvas>

--- all your controls -- 

     </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
```