# Automatic resize of nested UserControl does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, resize

In my application I use a `ContentControl` and dynamically fill it with a custom `UserControl`, using binding on `Content` to bind to a `FrameworkElement`. [EDITED: added example code to show the problem]

After some input of Steven and Charleh I created a small MVVM project to reproduce the problem. My MainWindow now looks like that:

```
    <Window x:Class="ResizeExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:ResizeExample.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ResizeExample"
    Title="ResizeExample"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Height="459"
    Width="795">
<Window.Resources>
    <localVM:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Windows1ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Windows1ViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Any Label on the right side" Canvas.Right="0" Canvas.Bottom="0"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ContentControl Name="ControlCanvas" Content="{Binding Path=externalView}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Setting `externalView` works fine, but it does not resize when the window is resized. Here how I implemented it in the ViewModel:

```
    private FrameworkElement _externalView;
    public FrameworkElement externalView
    {
        get { return this._externalView; }
        set
        {
            if (this._externalView != value)
            {
                this._externalView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => externalView);
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        externalView = new UserControl1();
    }
```

The `UserControl` contains a `TabControl` (which should resize) and everything else is in the `TabControl`. The `TabControl` contains some labels, text boxes and buttons (which should not resize) and a `DataGrid` (which should resize). At the moment the complete `TabControl` is minimized, because no size is set and it will not resize.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResizeExample.Views.UserControl1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="411" d:DesignWidth="805" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"   >
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1" Name="Tab1">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2" Name="Tab2">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="357" />
                <Label Content="Input some data 1:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,29,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Input some data 2:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,57,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Input some data 3:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,85,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinHeight="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,113,0,0" Name="releaseNotesGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="780" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I thought the controls would resize automatically, but this is not working. While I'm new to WPF and MVVM, it could be that I missed something basic.

I found [the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976393/wpf-user-control-does-not-resize-with-main-window) after which I removed the sizes and added the alignments, but this didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it now by testing a bit. The problem was the `TabControl` and `DataGrid` in the `UserControl`, which had Alignments that did not work with the stretch. This is now my `UserControl1` and it works fine for me:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ResizeExample.Views.UserControl1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1" Name="Tab1">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2" Name="Tab2" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="357" />
                <Label Content="Input some data 1:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,29,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Input some data 2:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,57,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="Input some data 3:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,85,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinHeight="200" Margin="6,113,0,0" Name="releaseNotesGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="780" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Thanks to Steven and Charleh to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Stevens answer, you may also need to set `ContentControl.HorizontalContentAlignment` and `ContentControl.VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` as `ContentControl` defaults are `Left` and `Top` respectively (as far as I recall)

Otherwise even though the `ContentControl` will fill the parent container, the content won't

Edit: Here's the default template for the `ContentControl` showing the default values...

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
              <ContentPresenter
                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                  Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Comment: I added the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to the ContentControl, but this doesn't solve the issue. I edited my post and added the full example.

Answer (score 1):

[`Canvas`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) does not automatically resize it's child contents to the container size.

Try using e.g. [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the Canvas will not resize automatically. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, but I added the code for an example how it looks at the moment.